# How to run normal windows .exe in raspberry PI running Windows IOT core

Tags: windows

I am very much new to windows core platform.

i have developed a console application in my normal windows 10 host machine using visual studio 2015 and it is working like a champ in local machine using intel(I5/I7) Processors.

Now i have to move my application to PI running windows IOT core. i did xcopy of my files and trying to run using power shell of my windows host machine but thing is.. i could not able run my application and getting below error message.

why my application is not running in PI? In fact my application is compiled for X86 platforms for intel processors. is this the really cause??  if so how do i compile my source code to target for ARM processors. please let me know the workaround. thanks in advance. [image]

Comment: Are you sure this will work?  I thought WIndows IOT only supported a very restricted set of programs.

Comment: " my application is compiled for X86 platforms for intel processors. is this the really cause" - yes, this is the real cause

Comment: Thanks. Is there any workaround for compile my code for ARM processors.

Comment: maybe [this](https://jaredrhodes.com/2018/01/01/creating-an-asp-net-core-application-for-raspberry-pi/) will help?

Comment: thanks jaromanda.. i have seen the link. probably that might not be helpful. my source code is ready and i am looking for tools to compile my source code for just ARM processors. because i don't want rewrite my application in .net core again..  thanks

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has guides on how to compile things for ARM processors.

First of all, you need the **complete source code** of the application including libraries it depends on.
Secondly, **you need lots of luck**. Windows 10 IoT **Core** is **not** a "full" version of Windows, and the things missing (Desktop, WinForms support) have been removed on purpose and are unlikely to be ever added.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/configuring-programs-for-arm-processors-visual-cpp